# How do I start ios shape animations at different times based on the position of another shape that is already moving

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, caanimation, cashapelayer

I'm trying to do the following animation for my iPhone App.  My current thoughts are to inherit from  CAShapeLayer and build up a shape that has the 3 components for the animation.  I.e. the yellow rectangle, the green line and the red pointer.  I have a basic animation working where I animate the yellow box, but now I'm wondering how to do I start the red pointer's animation at the right time.  The red pointer should only become visible when the top left corner of the rectangle moves past the blue point.

Is there a way to get the position of the yellow rectangle during the animation.  That way I could check the position and begin drawing and animating the red pointer and green line.

Or should I be researching a completely different method?

[image: Animation Frames]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the yellow layer's `presentationLayer`. The presentationLayer represents the currently displayed state of the layer, including animations.